# Sass and browser rendering

Tags: css, browser, sass

Does anybody know how how browser reading SASS? I learned how you can make sass file or how you can convert .css file in .sass and than compile it in new .css file that's more or less clear to me. But in the end you're getting new .css file again and than you include it in html. So whats happen with .sass file where, in which moment (if is there any) he becomes active during page-rendering process?

Comment: I just wanted to ask is the sass involved in process of page rendering and @Kanudo explained it to me pretty clear.

Comment: Kanudo happened to guess correctly.  It is unclear as to why you would think Sass has anything to do with the browser.  If browsers understood Sass, why would you need to install a Sass compiler?  Your question makes absolutely no sense in the context of Sass if you had done any amount of research at all before asking this question.

Comment: "Kanudo happened to guess correctly"?Look if you want to close question,play smart or whatever do it, thats good for you but not with me. I want to learn something here.That is what is it all about isnt it.Im new in web dev. you can see it in my profile and desperetly trying to get information. I explained in question what I did with sass and what remained unclear to me. I dont understand backend proceses well so I was searching for answers on other places and here amongst. I agree that something was wrong with title and some sentences and i correct that. But don tell me i didn do research pls

Comment: Somewhere here I saw question what is differents btw sass and scss? And that question has hundreds of votes. Are you kidding me? What you think is that person done some research? But again he/she is here to ask why not?

Comment: You may as well have asked "how does Java effect my ant farm?"  The "what is the difference between SCSS and SASS?" question came about at a time when the SCSS syntax was brand new and no one knew anything about it.  And no, you did not do any research (which includes experimentation).  This question is useless to future users because no one else on the planet is going to wonder the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SASS is a CSS pre-processor scripting language or you can say it is a scripting language that is interpreted into CSS and SASS is NOT used by browser during page rendering instead the generated CSS is used by the browser for rendering styles of the respected page.

SASS is scripting language which has programming features like any other programming or scripting language like `javascript`, `python`, etc. It has loops, conditional statements, functions which can be used like any other programming language.

In SASS power and advantages of programming techniques are used to write style sheets more efficiently and quickly.

Comment: Thank you for answer. What is still confusing me is when I open genereted .css it looks to me like a normal css file with css syntax... what diifferents does it make?

Comment: SASS is used to write CSS more efficiently. Here is an example to it... http://codepen.io/Bhavyesh/pen/ZQKdWP

Comment: So it's being used only for efficient writing not for improving your page rendering. And once you are finished with your writing you can practically delete all your saas file (or of course keep it for further manipulating witt css code). Is that correct?

Comment: Exactly. SASS does not effect page rendering by browser in any manner.