# Override primary color in Bootstrap 4 depending on body class?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4

I have a website where each section has its own primary color.

I'd like to put something in Bootstrap 4's Sass code, to override the primary color depending on a body class I set.

I have this, but it's not working so far:

```
$theme-colors: () !default;
$theme-colors: map-merge((
    // primary: $blue,
    // secondary: $gray-600,
    success: $green,
    info: $cyan,
    warning: $yellow,
    danger: $red,
    light: $gray-100,
    dark: $gray-800
), $theme-colors) !default;

// override according to portal
html {
    &.portal-1 {
        $theme-colors: map-merge((
            primary: #f1b36d
        ), $theme-colors);
    }
```

How can this be implemented in Bootstrap 4's Sass file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35521721/sass-and-browser-rendering

Comment: Here is an excellent explanation of how to accomplish this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41791461/iterate-over-theme-variable-files-in-scss#answers-header

Comment: Keep in mind that Sass is compiled into static CSS prior to runtime, so it can never have context of what's going on in your browser. So, if you're asking if you can override a variable throughout Bootstrap's Sass files based on the presence of a class on your page, you cannot. You would need to modify the Sass to cascade into all affected elements for that class and replace the variable throughout. Alternatively you could look into CSS custom variables, but browser support isn't all there right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the sass variables which are already converted to static CSS dynamically at the client side.
However, to build theme system you can apply one of the following options:

**1. Generate independent theme**

Put a theme argument in your build system which will generate different themes CSS Ex: `grunt build-sass --theme=brown`

```
var themes = {
    "default": "https://bootswatch.com/flatly/bootstrap.min.css",
    "cerulean" : "https://bootswatch.com/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css"
}

// Use something like this to add theme: (You can also append instead of overriding whole head html)
var headHTML = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML;
headHTML    += '<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="' + themes.cerulean +'">';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML = headHTML;
```

**2. Change properties based upon the parent class**

You can have a base CSS which defines general CSS. And then you can have separate CSS Properties based upon the parent

In the following example update `green-theme` class to `blue-theme` and vice versa

```css
div[class^=component] {
  display: inline-block;
  width:150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px gray;
  border-radius:1em;
}

/* Colors*/
$blue1: #3066BE; 
$blue2: #090C9B;
$green1: #5C946E; 
$green2: #80C2AF;

/* Blue Theme */
.blue-theme {
  .component1 {
    background-color: $blue1;
  }
  
  .component2 {
    background-color: $blue2;
   }
}
/* Green Theme */
.green-theme {
  .component1 {
    background-color: $green1;
  }
  
  .component2 {
    background-color: $green2;
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="green-theme" id="mainBody">
    <div class="component1">
    </div>
    
     <div class="component2">
    </div>
</div>
```

*Run Snippet won't work as we are using SCSS *

Answer (score 1):

Make a scss file structure like this,

```
- vendors
  - bootstrap
    - stylesheets /*[Bootstrap 4 official sass files]*/
      - _bootstrap.scss
- scss
  - themes
    - _theme-1.scss
    - _theme-2.scss
  - _variables.scss
  - styles.scss
  - portal-1.scss
  - portal-2.scss
```

#### _variables.scss

```
@import "../vendors/bootstrap/stylesheets/bootstrap/variables";
@import "../vendors/bootstrap/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins";
/* override bootstrap default variables ... */
/* custom variables with !default ... */
```

#### styles.scss

```
@import "variables";
@import "../vendors/bootstrap/stylesheets/bootstrap";
/* custom styles ... */
```

#### themes/_theme-1.scss

```
@import "../variables";
/* change value bootstrap and custom default variables ... */
$brand-primary:         #428bca
$brand-success:         #5cb85c;
$brand-info:            #5bc0de;
$brand-warning:         #f0ad4e;
$brand-danger:          #d9534f;
$body-bg:               #eff;
```

#### themes/_theme-2.scss

```
@import "../variables";
/* change value bootstrap and custom default variables ... */
$brand-primary:         #C04848;
```

#### portal-1.scss

```
@import "themes/_theme-1";
/* change style with new variable bootstrap default components ... */
.portal-1 {
    @import "../vendors/bootstrap/stylesheets/bootstrap/buttons";
    @import "../vendors/bootstrap/stylesheets/bootstrap/alerts";
   /* custom style overrides ... */
}
```

#### portal-2.scss

```
@import "themes/_theme-2";
/* change style with new variable bootstrap default components ... */
.portal-2 {
    @import "../vendors/bootstrap/stylesheets/bootstrap/buttons";
    @import "../vendors/bootstrap/stylesheets/bootstrap/alerts";
   /* custom styles from style.scss overrides ... */
}
```

After sass compilation we will get 3 files styles.css, portal-1.css and portal-2.css.
Use style.css by default and others include in head tag for theming.

```
<html>
    <head>
         <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
         <link href="portal-1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">BUTTON</button>
        <div class="portal-1">
            <button class="btn btn-primary">BUTTON</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: After searching a while for a simple solution, I though I could avoid the pain for anyone trying to achieve this:

You can use CSS variables to achieve this.

There is a thread on the main bootstrap github page [Github Issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/26596#issuecomment-601380068) and user @johanlef has posted a gist showing his method and the relevant code [gist](https://gist.github.com/johanlef/518a511b2b2f6b96c4f429b3af2f169a).

Then you can just make sure the css variables is initialized in you page

```
.body.theme1{
   --primary: #5d8be5;
}
```

I used for one of my multi tenanted website and it works great.

Comment: I added this to my CSS but nothing happened.

Comment: are you importing the functions override in the gist? This is quite old, so it's possible things have changed. You should move your css to bootstrap 5, i'm pretty it does it natively now.

Comment: It must be different for Bootstrap 5? Can it be done in that? (Looks like it can't -- you have to put `background-color: #whatever !important;` on everything)